# Where Are the Release Versions of ASP.Net AJAX 4.0 Templating Files?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to get the release version of ASP.Net AJAX 4.0 Templating working and can't find the JavaScript files.  With the beta version I needed to reference MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js, MicrosoftAjaxAdoNet.js, and MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js.

I can get everything to work with the beta CDN versions (e.g. http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js).  But for the life of me I can't find 1. The release CDN versions of these files or 2. Where to download the whole Release ASP.Net AJAX 4.0 JavaScript package.

The files certainly are not listed on the ASP.Net AJAX 4.0 CDN at http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNAjax4.ashx.  Maybe the files have been renamed?  Or if it's not released yet then when will it be and where is the latest version of these files on CodePlex?

Theoretically this should be a ridiculously easy question and I'm a little embarrased to even ask it on StackOverflow, but I've had no luck finding an answer on my own.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
- Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a ridiculous question as I struggled with the same problem a couple weeks ago.

The templating functionality isn't part of the ASP.NET 4.0 released files.  It has been moved to be part fo the Ajax Control Toolkit:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

And you can get the latest versions of the javascript files by downloading the source release from here:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/43475

However, I found that the April 12th version was a little problematic and so I am using the latest version from source control:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Once you get one of the downloads (either April 12 release or from source control), look in the Client/MicrosoftAjax folder for a Visual Studio project (2008 and 2010 are provided).  Build that project and it compiles the final .js files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer. It solved a lot of time for me as i was looking exactly for this. Please note that you need to install Ajax minifier 4.0 http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584 in order to compile this

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I was looking for this for two days.
After compiling the AjaxControlToolkit solutions, I had to add explicit reference to MicrosoftAjaxDataContext.js and MicrosoftAjaxTemplates.js script files on the ScriptManager, in order to use the template binding mechanism.

Comment: In addition I had to add references to MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftAjaxOpenData.js.